# How to use Semantic vector like Lucene to index and search document

Tags: java, lucene

I'm quite new to Java and Lucene . Lucene makes it easy to add full-text search capability to your application . In Lucene , I can do like http://www.lucenetutorial.com/lucene-in-5-minutes.html . But in semantic vectors I don't know how to index and search document like Lucene . Please help me !!

Comment: it's not clear what you've done already, and what you try to do with the semantic vectors. Any crisp explanation?

Comment: Hi Mysterion , I just want to know how to index my document in Semantic vectors . Can you help me ?

Comment: I'm doing a project  but It has to use Semantic vectors for Full text search .   My english is very bad so I can't explain what I want to say

Comment: if you want full text search you do not need to use semantic vectors, at least at 1 phase

Comment: But my project must use Semantic Vectors :D . Can you help me :((

Comment: But my project must use Semantic Vectors :D . Can you help me :(( –